# How to deal with mutable variable in scala

Tags: scala

ScalaStyle doesn't allow mutable variables. Sample code:

```
object Configuration {

  var auroaDbConfig: AuroraConnectionParameter = null
  def getConfigration() = {
    val rootConfig: Config = ConfigFactory.load()
    //for aurora configuration
    auroaDbConfig = rootConfig
      .as[AuroraConnectionParameter]("mdpApp.aurora")
    //for spark configuration
    val sparkConfig: SparkConnectionParameter = rootConfig
      .as[SparkConnectionParameter]("mdpApp.spark")
    //for cassandra configuration
    val cassandraDbConfig: CassandraConnectionParameter = rootConfig
      .as[CassandraConnectionParameter]("mdpApp.cassandra")
    //for s3 configuration
    val s3Config: S3ConnectionParameter = rootConfig
      .as[S3ConnectionParameter]("mdpApp.s3")

  }

}
```

Use Case : the  `ConfigFactory.load()` is to be called only once
so placed it into a function which would be called once in the code & other variable are called as per required in the code

How do I refactor the code, so that variables are initliazed in the functions and called when and where required in the code

Answer (score 2):

Key word `lazy` is exactly for this case. We wanna load something once, but only load only when we need it.

Without keyword `lazy` in this example is also OK.

```
object Configuration {

  lazy val rootConfig: Config = ConfigFactory.load()
  lazy val auroaDbConfig: AuroraConnectionParameter = rootConfig
      .as[AuroraConnectionParameter]("mdpApp.aurora")
  lazy val sparkConfig: SparkConnectionParameter = rootConfig
      .as[SparkConnectionParameter]("mdpApp.spark")
    //for cassandra configuration
  lazy val cassandraDbConfig: CassandraConnectionParameter = rootConfig
      .as[CassandraConnectionParameter]("mdpApp.cassandra")
    //for s3 configuration
  lazy val s3Config: S3ConnectionParameter = rootConfig
      .as[S3ConnectionParameter]("mdpApp.s3")

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  def getConfigration() : AuroraConnectionParameter = {
    val result = rootConfig
      .as[AuroraConnectionParameter]("mdpApp.aurora")
    // snip
    result
  }
  val auroaDbConfig = getConfiguration()
```

I believe will do what you are asking, if I understand your question correctly. You could also, of course, just execute that `rootConfig.as[AuroraConnectionParameter]...` as the last statement in the function and it will behave the same as capturing the variable and returning it. Whichever fits your style and other constraints.

Comment: But this is not just one variable, I have 4 similar variables.And have to make sure that rootconfig is declared only once